# MinGW gcc isn't able to compile a simple test program(same with cygwin) in CLion

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, path, clion

I've just installed CLion and i needed compiler. I installed Cygwin. 
But there was an error:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.

Error code: 1
```

So, CMake was "bundled" and i tried to install it from site. But there was the next error:

```
 Selected CMake might be incompatible with the Cygwin environment.
In order to run on Cygwin, CMake needs to be specially compiled.
Please select either CMake bundled with CLion or CMake from the Cygwin installation.


CMake Error: The source directory "/cygdrive/c/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Error code: 1
```

Then i've tried to install MinGW - this time it was the following problem:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at D:/CLion 182.2574.4/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "D:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"D:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_a4ce5/fast"
    D:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_a4ce5.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4ce5.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/в•§СЋС‹в„–С‡СЋС‚СЂР„С…С‹в„–/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4ce5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    D:\MinGW\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_a4ce5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\в•ЁРЇв•Ёв•›в•Ёв•—в•¤Рњв•Ёв•–в•Ёв•›в•Ёв–“в•Ёв–‘в•¤Р’в•Ёв•Ўв•Ёв•—в•¤Рњ\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\в•ЁРЇв•Ёв•›в•Ёв•—в•¤Рњв•Ёв•–в•Ёв•›в•Ёв–“в•Ёв–‘в•¤Р’в•Ёв•Ўв•Ёв•—в•¤Рњ\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_a4ce5.dir\build.make:65: CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4ce5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/в•§СЋС‹в„–С‡СЋС‚СЂР„С…С‹в„–/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:125: cmTC_a4ce5/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

In both cases it's problems with **paths**, i think. I tried to give root to CLion, gcc, etc. - nothing.
I've tried to find logs or just way to this path - but all was worthless - path doesn't exist.I just can't find out, why that's happening. 
Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem with encodings somewhere between windows/cygwin/clion/cmake (I assume you user name is non-ascii).

As a quick workaround try:

- installing CLion in the location without non-latin symbols
- changing CLion's `system` and `config` folders to the location without non-latin symbols. [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs)

And to troubleshoot the problem, could you please check if the cygwin's console shows the user home path correctly? (e.g. use `ls /cygdrive/c/Users/`, then `cd` to the user home path).
If Cygwin can correctly work with the user home, could you please [file a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) and attach CLion's log files? (Help | Show Log in Explorer)

Comment: Yep, i've changed folders `system` and `config` - nothing. It's funny, but there is new error -
`The source directory "/cygdrive/c/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`